# Limits of sequence $(1 + \frac{3}{n^2})^{n^2}$ as n tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1 + \frac{3}{n^2})^{n^2}$ and I've been given the following:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $n^{1/n}$ = 1, $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $a^{1/n}$ = 1 and $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}$ = e.

My first thoughts were to use the 3rd limit so $(1 + \frac{3}{n^2})^{n^2}$ <= 3e$^{n}$
and then using the squeeze theorem to show as n tends to infinity the sequence is null, but I think I'm missing something out.

Comment: Hint:Let $N=\frac{n^2}{3}$,then try to use $\lim(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$

Comment: @Gingerjin so ${e^(n^{2})/3} $ and as n tends to infinity e = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\Bigl(1+\textstyle{3\over n^2}\Bigr)^{n^2}=\Bigl(\Bigl(1+{1\over n^3/3}\Bigr)^{n^2/3}\Bigr)^3
$$
Note that $n^2/3\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

You might also need to show that, for $x$ a *real* variable 
$$\tag{1}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (1+\textstyle{1\over x})^x =e.
$$
One way to show this is the following:  for $x>1$,
$$\textstyle
\bigl( 1+{1\over x}\bigr)^x \le \bigl(1+{1\over \lfloor x\rfloor} \bigr)^{\lceil  x\rceil}=
 \bigl(1+{1\over \lfloor x\rfloor} \bigr)^{\lfloor  x\rfloor +1}=
 \bigl(1+{1\over \lfloor x\rfloor} \bigr)^{\lfloor  x\rfloor } 
\bigl(1+{1\over \lfloor x\rfloor} \bigr)^{1} 
$$
and
$$\textstyle
\bigl( 1+{1\over x}\bigr)^x 
\ge \bigl(1+{1\over \lceil x\rceil} \bigr)^{\lfloor  x\rfloor}
=\bigl(1+{1\over \lceil x\rceil} \bigr)^{\lceil  x\rceil -1}
=\bigl(1+{1\over \lceil x\rceil} \bigr)^{\lceil  x\rceil } \bigl(1+{1\over \lceil x\rceil} \bigr)^{-1}. 
$$
Apply the Squeeze Theorem  to show that $(1)$ holds.

Comment: this eventually makes the solution e^3 right?

Comment: @franky Yes, indeed.